# UIView animation

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, iphone-sdk-3.1

I have a UIView(first view) on top of which I would like to display another UIView(second view). I display the second view using animation which causes the second view to be displayed for about 3/4 of the iPhone screen. The first view is visible underneath the animated second view. I would like to make changes to the first view as the second view is displayed. Any ideas on how I can achieve this. Right now, the animation completes, the second view is displayed and then I can change the first view. I would like to change the layout of the first screen as the second screen is being displayed. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, just do it.

You can start more than one animation at a time.  If you are not animating the changes to the first view, then do them after calling commitAnimations or otherwise starting the animations on the second view.  If you want to do them half way through the animation, set up a timer or delayed call.